# Pharo doesn't save temporary variable names

Tags: pharo

Hello Pharo community,

I am following instructions based on [PharoByExample](http://books.pharo.org/updated-pharo-by-example/pdf/2018-09-29-UpdatedPharoByExample.pdf).

In chapter 3.6 when I paste the code of `initialize` method in the browser and Accept it, I see that temporary variables are renamed as `tmp1 tmp2 tmp3 tmp4`:

```
initialize
    | tmp1 tmp2 tmp3 tmp4 |
    super initialize.
    tmp4 := self cellsPerSide.
    tmp1 := LOCell new.
    tmp2 := tmp1 width.
    tmp3 := tmp1 height.
    self
        bounds: (5 @ 5 extent: (tmp2 * tmp4) @ (tmp3 * tmp4) + (2 * self borderWidth)).
    cells := Matrix
        new: tmp4
        tabulate: [ :arg1 :arg2 | self newCellAt: arg1 at: arg2 ]
```

How should I fix this problem?

I am using Pharo 6.0 (Latest update: #60546) on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: the comments are not saving as well.

Comment: That's probably because you can't access your `.sources` / `.changes` file. Are you using a one-click application? See if this helps: `Smalltalk openSourceFiles`.

Answer (score 1):

This is typical of a missing .sources and .changes files, like you cannot write to them or they are corrupt in some way.

So, what happens is that there is some decompilation occuring and temps are shown like what you see.

Did you install Pharo in, like, Program Files ? That would trigger such stuff if you are not an admin user (Windows). Linux can do the same based on rights you have got.

Try to use the Pharo Launcher, it will be easier for you to avoid this.